# Webscraping code using asyncio is freezing. Script is not stopping nor returning an exception

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-asyncio, playwright, playwright-python

I am building a webscraper using asyncio and Playwright. I am running into issues that I do not know how to debug as I really do not understand what is going on, so not sure where to start from.
I have OVERLYsimplified my code here so you guys can see what I am doing. I am hopeful that despite the simplification, it will still provide enough information for someone to point the possible issue(s).

So what is happening:
In summary, when I really test my script, meaning I run dozens of tasks, at some point the code freezes and does not resume. Important to mention that I am monitoring my task manager throughout my testing, and very few times does my CPU reaches 100% and when it does, it usually goes back down. My RAM is never maxed out, so please keep that in mind. I do not think it is a resources problem, I am sure it is something else with the code or the way I built it.

I have coded it in a way that I only use two browser instances with as many browser_context as tasks I have (according to Playwright’s best practices and documentation). This certainly lowers the stress on my system and I can see things happen more quickly, but still it freezes.
I have decided to use Headless=False just to check what is going on, and I can see all browsers opening, I can see the navigation/searching happening, but at some point, it just stops. Asyncio never goes back to the opened browsers and the whole script freezes. There is no timeouterror, nothing. I just simply stalls and doesnt continue.

I have modified/played with different timeout values hoping it would give time to the script to go back to each browser and finish the code, but I am not certain that is the issue. It just seems like at some point, it loses track of what it was doing and never goes back to the remaining browsers.

Understandings:
I thought that after my timeout expires it would throw and exception, hence that particular task would fail/close and at least I would get that reported with my code. But that doesnt happen. Doesnt appear the code encounters an exception because I do not see the different messages I coded appear in my console.
I thought that running on Headless would speed up the time it takes to go through the browser phase of my script, hence avoiding timeouts, but again, it stalls/freezes in headless or headed.

All that said, my script works fine when I have a handful of browser_context opened but if I increase the number of tasks, then it simply freezes and never completes running, nor times-out.

Here is what I am seeing:

1. One of the two websites (website1 in my code below)  I am scraping allows me to enter the search parameters directly on the URL, hence the page opens with the data I want to scrape. This makes it usually much faster than website 2. Website 2, requires me to access the homepage, enter my search parameters and then click "search" to get the results.  In essence, this allows my code to almost always access website1's info faster than website2.
2. I see all my tabs opening, the script goes through all the process of entering search parameters and navigating to the results page just fine. This means that all tasks for Website1 would finish and close (according to my code) and all tasks for Website2 would reach the results page but stay there. The script would not continue to closing the tab and initiating the parsing.

Assumptions and results:

1 - My first assumption was that given that parsing HTML in my code is a blocking process, at some point after gathering all the html from all tasks from website1, my script would continue moving through the parsing process (which takes a bit of time) and hence at some point it would just “forget” or  “lose track” of all the browsers from website2 that were still pending. Although this really doesnt make sense at all.

**What I did**: This is why I started playing with asyncio.sleep (you will see that in my code below). I simply thought that if I could delay website1 for at least 60s, that would give enough time for website2 to access the search results, gather the html and then website1 tasks would kick in.

**Results**: This seemed to “sort of work” but it was super inconsistent. Yes, i did manage to get website2 tasks to gather html and parse it, but at some point, again, it would freeze and website1 would not complete.

2 - I began playing with the try:except block (as you can see in the code) to see if that would help. Initially I was getting a lot of errors from my proxies so I made a while loop that it would retry with a different proxy when it returned a connection error. I also assumed that since there are so many tabs opened at the same time, perhaps my network bandwidth wasn’t big enough to load the data from all, so if a timeout occurred it would simply retry again with another proxy. As you can see in the code, if any of those errors occurs, I would get a printed statement stating that was th problem and that it would retry with a different proxy.

**Results**: Nothing to report. Whatever is happening is not triggering those exceptions, since I am not seeing those messages printed in my console. So hypothesis was wrong

3 - Assuming that perhaps my single cpu thread was being maxed out, I tried to convert the parsing process to an asyncio task via “await asyncio.to_thread” method, but I never got it working. I always got an error that I had not “awaited” that task, and I do not understand why. I also do not really know if that had helped my problem or not. Thoughts? For context, I moved the entire HTML ;parsing to its own function and try triggering it at the end of the browser process (as seen commented out in website1's code below). For some reason that is not working, so I really never got to test if that would help or not

I am 100% certain I am oversimplifying everything I have attempted to solve or understand my issue and I am certain I am missing dozens of  other things I have tried to fix it, but I cannot even remember everything I have tried. At this point I am very lost and not sure how to fix this.

Can someone identify the issue that may be causing the whole program to stall?
Why if there is an error or exception, doens’t the gather (*tasks, return_excption = True) captures them and terminates the execution?
Why does the whole script freezes and doesnt continue?
Why are my timeouts not seem to be working, or what else other than the timeouts is causing the whole thing to stall?
Why is asyncio never going back to the open tabs? It does everything fine for website1 and it navigates to the results page for website2, but it never continues with parsing through the HTML?

I know my code is not perfect (I am still fairly new and learning), so feel free to make recommendations if you see anything that would make it better or more resilient. However, I do ask you to not simply focus your response in criticizing my coding skills. Please help me understand what is going on so I can learn, make my script more resilient and fix the underlying issue

Below is the code that appears in my main module. Here is the logic I follow to build the tasks and then the tasks that initiate each website.

```
import time
from search_data import Search_Parameters
from playwright.async_api import Playwright, async_playwright, expect
import asyncio

success_list = []



  async def website1(search_data: Search_Parameters):
    global list1, list2
    user_info = search_data
    # await asyncio.sleep(60)
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        browser = await playwright.firefox.launch(headless=False)
        async_1_results = [asyncio.create_task(A1_Search.search_availability(user_info,day,c,o, browser)) for day in range(user_info.flexibility+1) for c in list1 for o in list2]
        a1_results = await asyncio.gather(*async_1_results)
    for a1_result in a1_results:
        if a1_result[0] == "No Results":
            print("No Results")
        elif a1_result[0] == "Error":
            print("Error Found")
        else:
            success_list.append(a1_result[1])


async def website2(search_data: Search_Parameters):
    global list1, list2
    user_info = search_data
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        browser = await playwright.firefox.launch(headless=False)
        async_2_results = [asyncio.create_task(A2_Search.search_availability(user_info,day,c,o,browser)) for day in range(user_info.flexibility+1) for c in list1 for o in list2]
        a2_results = await asyncio.gather(*async_2_results)
    for a2_result in a2_results:
        if a2_result[0] == "No Results":
            print("No Results")
        elif a2_result[0] == "Error":
            print("Error Found")
        else:
            success_list.append(a2_result[1])

async def search_logic():
    tasks = []
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(website1(user_info),name="A1"))
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(website2(user_info),name="A2"))
    async_results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks,return_exceptions=True)

    for _ in range (len(async_results)):
        if async_results[_] == None:
            pass
        else:
            #Code to save the error/exception in a txt file

    '''
    Code continues to convert success_list into a pandas dataframe.
    '''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(search_logic())
    print(f"Total time it took to run: {time.perf_counter() - start:0.2f} seconds")
'''
```

Below is the function (from another module) that searches website 1. I added some asyncio.sleep in this code hoping it would give enough time to website2 to retrieve all the html. This sometimes work but not always, so I assume something else is going on. I also tried the await asyncio.to_thread in here, but always got an error.

```
async def A1_search(self,search_data:Search_Parameters,iteration,c,o,browser:Playwright):
    success_list = []
    user_info = search_data
    proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)
    date = (datetime.datetime.strptime(user_info.searchDate, "%m/%d/%y") + datetime.timedelta(
        days=iteration)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    loop = False
    while not loop:
        context = await browser.new_context(proxy={"server": f'http://{proxy}'})
        page = await context.new_page()
        # await page.route("**/*", self.intercept_route)
        try:
            await page.goto("https://website1 that takes search parameters in the url directly")
            await expect(page).to_have_url(re.compile("https://www.website1/*"),timeout=60000)
        except PlaywrightTimeoutError:
            print(f"Timeout error, trying new proxy.")
            proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)
            await context.close()
        except Exception as e:
                if "ERR_TIMED_OUT" in str(e) or "ERR_INVALID_AUTH_CREDENTIALS" in str(e) or "NS_ERROR_PROXY_CONNECTION_REFUSED" in str(e):
                    print(f"AC ERR_TIMED_OUT, trying new proxy")
                    proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)
                    await context.close()
                else:
                    print (f"Something else occured that needs to get debugged.")
                    print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
                    proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)
                    await context.close()
                    print ("Trying again")
        else:
            loop = True

    await page.get_by_role("button", name="Close").click(timeout=60000)

    #Code below just activates some checkboxes if they appear on the site (they dont always show up)
    try:
        await page.get_by_role("button", name="More options").click(timeout=60000)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        await page.get_by_text("Number").click(timeout=2000)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        await page.get_by_text("Mixed").click(timeout=1000)
    except:
        pass

    await page.get_by_role("button", name="Close").click(timeout=60000)
    content = await page.content()
    await context.close()
    # await asyncio.to_thread(self.parsing,content,origin,destination,user_info,date,printed_date)
    html = HTML(html=content)
    await asyncio.sleep(60)

    '''
    below html parsing code using requests-html. This has been tested multiple times and it works fine
    '''

    return "Results",success_list
```

Below is the code I use for website2. Note that this one requires extra steps to enter search parameters and click on submit. Again, I can see my script doing all this and actually reaching the results page. It just never goes beyond that point:

```
async def A2_search(self, search_data: Search_Parameters, iteration, c, o,browser: Playwright):
    success_list = []
    user_info = search_data
    proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)
    date = (datetime.datetime.strptime(user_info.searchDate, "%m/%d/%y") + datetime.timedelta(
        days=iteration)).strftime("%m/%d/%y")

    loop = False
    while not loop:
        context = await browser.new_context(proxy={"server": f'http://{proxy}'})
        page = await context.new_page()
        # await page.route("**/*", self.intercept_route)
        try:
            await page.goto(f"https://website2", timeout=120000)
        except PlaywrightTimeoutError:
            print(f"Timeout error, trying new proxy. Bad proxy {proxy}")
            proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)
            await context.close()
        except Exception as e:
            if "NS_ERROR_NET_TIMEOUT" in str(e) or "ERR_INVALID_AUTH_CREDENTIALS" in str(
                    e) or "NS_ERROR_PROXY_CONNECTION_REFUSED" in str(e) or "NS_ERROR_PROXY_BAD_GATEWAY" in str(e):
                print(f"AS - ERR TIMEOUT or Invalid credentials, trying new proxy. Bad proxy: {proxy}")
                proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)
                await context.close()
            elif await page.title() == "Access to this page has been denied":
                print(f"Denied proxy {proxy}. Removed")
                proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)
                await context.close()
            elif await page.title() == "Problem loading page":
                print(f"Problem loading page with proxy: {proxy}")
                proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)
                await context.close()
            else:
                print(f"Something else happened that needs to get debugged. Proxy: {proxy}")
                print(f"Error {str(e)}")
                return ("Error",None)
        else:
            # following code enters the search parameters needed and then clicks "search" to bring the results page
            await page.get_by_label("former").check()
            await page.get_by_label("number").check()
            await page.get_by_role("textbox", name="Date").clear()
            await page.get_by_role("textbox", name="Date").fill(date)
            await page.get_by_role("textbox", name="Date").press("Enter")
            await page.wait_for_url("https://website2resultspage", timeout=60000)

            loop = True

    content = await page.content()
    await context.close()

    html = HTML(html=content)
    await asyncio.sleep(10)

    '''
    below html parsing code using requests-html. This has been tested multiple times and it works fine
    '''

    return "Results", success_list
```